# Is there a way to obtain system information or cpu information using Adobe Flex?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, properties, adobe, cpu

I want to build a program built around my pc specs. Is there a way to access such information as how much ram I have or how much cpu usage is being consumed, etc.?

Comment: Why do you want to use Flex to solve this?  There are many GUI applications which can be used to display system stats.  It would help to know why you chose Flex as opposed to an open-source solution, or a more conventional language (e.g. Python, Ruby, Java, etc.).

Comment: @bedwyr Why isn't Flex considered an open source solution?

Comment: I can easily do it with Java, I just want to open up my knowledge and learn how different things work in different languages.

Comment: @Flextras, whoops - bad wording. My intent was to ask why the OP wants to use Flex to build something which has either already been solved (e.g. existing open-source apps to display this information), or would be better suited to a server-side language. I wasn't trying to imply Flex isn't open-source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, not in a Flex web app.  The browser's security sandbox would prevent such information from being passed into a browser plugin.

You may be able to do this in AIR by using the [NativeProcess](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/quickstart/articles/interacting_with_native_process.html) functionality.  You'd have to create your own program to get the system details you need and then pass them back to your running Flex Application.  I imagine this approach would need completely different implementations for each platform you wanted to deploy to.  ( Mac and PC ).

Answer (score 0):

You could build a web service which runs on your PC and reports system stats upon request.  From there, you could build a Flex app to display the information from the web service.

Frankly, this only really makes sense if you have a need to gather system stats across a network.  Otherwise, Flextras' comment makes the most sense: use AIR or another language which has functionality for gathering system stats.